# XDCMP for controlling desktop

Tags: 21.04, remote-access

Can XDCMP be used to view the current user session / desktop?

I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 and have modified my `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file so the `xdmcp` section looks like

```
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
Port=177
```

However, whenever I connect to it, it wants me to try and log into the machine. What I am after is seeing the currently logged in user's desktop and being to see what they are doing / take control.

---

I am aware that there are alternatives to this such as Vino and NoMachine that provide this functionality, but I am specifically interested in XDCMP for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xdmcp is a login protocol, it isn't a screen sharing protocol.
It is functioning as designed.

If you want to see the current logged in user's desktop, you will need to use screen sharing software like vnc and enable vncserver in the session you want to view.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I appreciate the clarification